# How to simplify or factor this equation

Tags: factoring

$$1 = x + 2\cdot x$$

How can I simplify this formula for $x$.

Comment: Are you actually looking for the roots of $x^2+x-1$? If so, you could start [reading this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) and you will be able to proudly solve it on your own. If not, apologies, I have no idea what you are asking then.

Comment: What is $x(2)$? Is it a $x^2$ or something else?

Comment: it's x times 2 or x*2 or x(2)

Comment: @julien I've updated the question.

Comment: @AustinMohr I've updated the question

Comment: @julien thanks for the link. I remember being real good @ this in high school but sadly forgot how to do this!

Comment: @m0nhawk thanks for updating the question - I see now why everyone was confused. this was first post on this site. Thanks

Comment: Wait, if this is $1=x+2x=3x$, this is trivially $x=\frac{1}{3}$ (in the real or complex numbers).

Comment: 5 star! period. will get +1 from me.

Comment: I just made up number 1 and 2, I was looking more for the steps involved.. like multiply on one side, divide on the other.. this one gets me.

Comment: @Kaster not the toughest question on here, I'm sure.. but its a doozy! :P

Comment: ... and if someone could please explain (seriously) how to solve this step by step, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: @Ben julien's answer is best you can get.

Answer (score 3):

By equivalent transform of terms/equations:
$$\begin{align} 1&=x+2x \\
1&=1\cdot x+2\cdot x \\
1&=(1+2)\cdot x \\
1&=3\cdot x \\
1/3&=x
\end{align}$$
In the last step we have divided by $3$ both sides of the equations. In the previous steps we used the *unit* and *distributive* properties: 
 $1\cdot x=x$ and $(a+b)\cdot x=a\cdot x+b\cdot x$.

Answer (score 0):

$$1 = x + 2 \cdot x$$
This can be simplified to:
$$1 = x + 2x$$
Remember that you can combine these terms by adding the coefficients (the numbers attached to the $x$'s).
$$1 = 1x + 2x$$
$$1 = 3x$$
Now we have to isolate $x$. Divide both sides by 3.
$$\frac{1}{3} = \frac{3x}{3}$$
$$\frac{1}{3} = x$$
I hope this post helped!